# Не вызывается окно выбора приложений для действия

Tags: java, android, webview

Есть страница сайта, на которой находится форма загрузки файлов.
Если открыть ее через любой мобильный браузер, то вылетит стандартное андройдовское окно для выбора метода загрузки (камера, файлы и тд)

В webview такого действия почему-то не происходит...
Разрешения на камеру и внешнее хранилище в манифесте прописаны.

**решения описаны тут:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29045637/html-input-type-file-is-not-working-on-webview-in-android-there-is-any-way-to**

Comment: Код в студию (что вы делаете в `WebView`)

Answer (score 0):

Это нормально. Webview не поддерживает загрузку файлов таким образом. Во всяком случае до 4.4.4.